# Dynamic requires in nodejs before module.exports

Tags: node.js

I have an app I'm working on that has active directory login and local login. When checking for permissions I want to allow permissions to either be set by AD group membership, or if not using AD then locally stored permissions in the database. As a result I have 2 different modules to handle permission checks. Is there a way to have a require at the top, before module.exports to be done dynamically through an if statement or something similar? I thought I could assign a process.env.isLocal and process from there but it doesn't seem to work I get an error that says Permissions is not defined

```
const moment = require('moment');
const AdminPortal = require('../models/adminportal');
if(process.env.isLocal) {
    const Permissions = require('../models/localLogin/localPermissions');
} else {
    const Permissions = require('../models/permissions');
}
const isAuthenticated = require("../config/middleware/isAuthenticated");
const config = require("../config/configFile.js").get(process.env.NODE_ENV.trim());
module.exports = function(app){
```

I suppose maybe I need to have both code sets in one file and then choose which one to use based on if its a local login or not, I was just hoping to keep them separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue with the `Permissions` variable is that it's block scoped so it's only available inside the block in which you declare it.  So, this:

```
if(process.env.isLocal) {
    const Permissions = require('../models/localLogin/localPermissions');
} else {
    const Permissions = require('../models/permissions');
}
```

Creates a `Permissions` variable that is only usable within the `if/else` block.  If you want it to be available at a higher scope and use the same `if/else` construct, then you have to declare the variable at that higher scope which means you can't use `const`:

```
let Permissions;
if(process.env.isLocal) {
    Permissions = require('../models/localLogin/localPermissions');
} else {
    Permissions = require('../models/permissions');
}

// you can use Permissions here
```

FYI, this is a place where the ternary operator can be useful:

```
const Permissions = process.env.isLocal ? 
     require('../models/localLogin/localPermissions') : 
     require('../models/permissions');
```

Comment: Ha, that is so obvious I should have known. Unfortunately it doesnt seem to read the value correctly, because even though the route console.logs true, its always choosing the false require.